# vba code to stop script if a column does not appear

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the following code to work as follows: Search for specific columns in a table and if they dont occur, then stop the script and display a message box with something like "Error: Not all required columns are present".

This is the code:

```
Sub Find_Columns()

Dim rngToSearch As Range
Dim WhatToFind As Variant
Dim iCtr As Long

Set rngToSearch = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:XFD1048576")

WhatToFind = Array("Apples", "Oranges", "Pears") 'add all Column header that you want to check

With rngToSearch
    For iCtr = LBound(WhatToFind) To UBound(WhatToFind)
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngToSearch, WhatToFind(iCtr)) = 0 Then
           MsgBox WhatToFind(iCtr) & "Error: Not all columns are there"    Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Side note: `Set rngToSearch = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:XFD1048576")` can just be `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells` or maybe better, `.UsedRange`.

Comment: That said, what's the error or problem? Are these table headers you're looking for?

Comment: My code doesn't work

Comment: Unfortunately "doesn't work" isn't helpful. Can you be more specific?

Comment: It doesn't exit the sub

Comment: Everything else works fine

Comment: Are these supposed to be an exact match or only match part of a cell?

Comment: they should be an exact match

Comment: Get rid of the `With` and `End With` - you aren't using them - then make sure the `Exit Sub` is on a different line (typo in the question?), change `Range("A1:XFD1048576")` to `UsedRange`. Other than that, I'd need some source data or a screenshot to help further.

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Comment: If it's actually a table, and you don't want false positives, then you don't want to use `UsedRange` because a table range can be smaller than the "used range".  Imagine one of your search terms is in a cell 30 columns to the right of the table.  It's not in the table but `UsedRange` doesn't care, it'll count it.  If there is only one table in the sheet... `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").ListObjects(1).HeaderRowRange`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code. I have tested and it is working.

```
For Each cell In Range("A1:A5").Cells
        If Not IsInArray(cell.Value, WhatToFind) Then
            MsgBox "Error:Not Matched"
            Exit Sub
        End If
Next cell

Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) = stringToBeFound Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    IsInArray = False

End Function
```